# Увеличить изображение относительно центра своего родителя

Tags: zoom, вычислительная-геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить задачку.

Как вычислить смещение изображения так, чтобы при изменении его масштаба казалось, что область просмотра родителя, словно бы, становится ближе/дальше к изображению?
Изображение, при этом, можно перемещать в любое место внутри области просмотра.

Comment: что значит область просмотра родителя ?

Comment: Любое окно, в котором отображается информация, в данном случае - <div>, в котором находится <img>.